# Share Database connection between objects

Tags: c#, database, wcf, database-connection

I am going back and forth with this changing my design multiple times.

I have Two classes `Shop` & `Source`,
each `Shop` has `IList<Product>` (approx. 1000 products),
and `Source` has `IList<Item>` (approx 200),
**All Classes needs to perform some actions on the same Database.**

At first, I shared an open `DbConnection` with all objects:
And when building my **WebService** it became problematic,
I cached the open static `DbConnection` (bad as it sounds) and used it.
but it started making trouble when testing multiple requests, when the connection closed sporadically and `ExecuteReader()` threw (wasn't using MARS).

After reading [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query) and many other sources suggesting to rely on connection pooling.
I replaced my code to open a connection just before I query, and dispose of it when finished.
but I notice a degredation in performance.
**Can I check how the pool is functioning (or isn't it?)**

Question: How can I monitor my SqlConnection pool?

Question: Is there any other design to share this connection between these many objects.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance degradation may not be related to how you manage the database connection. Generally, re-creating connections isn't a costly operation and .NET will pool / manage them for you. You should be able to create as many connections as you want, just ensure you are properly disposing them. There could be issues with the underlying queries or other areas of your application that you may need to consider.

> How can I monitor my SqlConnection pool?

- There are [Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503(v=vs.110).aspx) you can look at.
- Take a look at using [perfmon](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/monitoring-database-connections/)

> Is there any other design to share this connection between these many
>   objects.

How are you reading the connection string? That itself could be static, but I would still rely on connection pooling (as you noted from your research). Are you properly disposing the connections?

Example (static connection string):

```
    public static readonly string ConnectionString connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YOURCONNECTION"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    private void TestMethod()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
            string query = "select ....";
            using (var dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, dbConn)) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ConnectionString is a member of each class, though same string.  I Am using `using` block for all Connection, Command & Reader. 
I'll take a look at my statistics, Everything points to the conclusion I might be slipping something else.

Comment: @TomerW I would create a utility class that you can put this in. No reason to duplicate this in all your classes.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know exactly what i changed, but after messing around with the code, it is running lightning speed constantly :)